# How to make a Unicode-standardized character (preferably UTF-8) from a vector (SVG) image?

Tags: vector, typography, icon, automation, unicode

I have a `.svg` file containing a vector image of [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) logo.

The file is available [here in Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:WhatsApp.svg) and from what I can tell it's free to use.

I want to paste it as text in my website as a comfortable way to combine in HTML documents without storing an image file and without referencing to it and maintaining the image path in the HTML code.

How to make, from that vector icon, a Unicode-standardized textual character (preferably UTF-8)?

A WhatsApp character that would be similar to these:

- ☎
- 
- ✆
- 

Is there any function common in graphic design programs which does so automatically, somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe I misunderstand, but since Unicode is a *standard* you can't just add characters yourself. Then it wouldn't be a standard. If you made a custom font or a custom version of a font which contains that logo, you would have to instead maintain the font path in the HTML code so I can't see how that would be easier. Linking to an image is a completely normal thing to do. If you for some reason want to avoid this you could have the SVG code inline instead of linking to a file. But then the SVG code must be present in all your HTML files.

Comment: @Wolff thanks a lot, I just want a textual character to work with, which modern browsers (Chrome, Edge, FireFox) would easily recognize, instead of an image.

Comment: @Wolff coding the SVG inside the HTML is an action I find interesting, although it would likely create an astonishingly broad row of input ... Perhaps I should call the svg file from Wiki Commons directly, instead from my server :)

Comment: You could of course link to Wikimedia Commons. Comes with a minor risk of course. The file might be removed or change path. The site could be down. I don't understand the reluctance to link to a file on your server. Doesn't your site contain other graphics and images?

Comment: @Wolff I normally **would** store a free file and link to its local version as with `src="/.file.svg"` or `src="/file.svg"` but I had a strange problem in which only `src="https://domain.tld/rest_of_the_path"` worked, perhaps due to some unreported JS bug or a local content-management-system bug which I couldn't debug and yet didn't want a full link. I count on MediaWiki's server in this particular special case.

Comment: MediaWiki's == WikiCommon's *

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is have a Unicode character such as [U+2706](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2706/index.htm) (✆) represented by a specific vector image (e.g., the WhatsApp icon) in all your web pages.

What you need to do is create your own font that contains this image at the corresponding code point. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is by using the [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select). Select the WhatsApp icon and click the "Font" button:

[image: Screenshot of the IcoMoon website with the WhatsApp icon selected]

On the next page, paste the character you want to associate with this glyph, or just type in the corresponding code point (2706), then click the "Download" button:

[image: Screenshot of the next page, showing how to specify the code point for this glyph]

You'll then receive a set of files that you can use to embed this font into your web pages. Put this font at the start of the list in your `font-family` CSS rules (e.g., `body { font-family: icomon, Arial, sans-serif; }`). Any characters missing from the first font (i.e., everything except ✆) will be displayed using fonts that appear later in the list.

You can of course add other icons to your font if you like. IcoMoon's documentation pages explain the process in more detail.

Comment: Hello, thanks ! I ought to just copy and paste a character which was created "in-vivo" out of a program. I give the program the svg icon as input and get a character to copy-paste as output (and it would be recognized by all major webbrowsers). I understand that what you suggest is a bit different and requires CSS, or that such technology (as I seek) currently doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnsonTarof, where would the vector data be stored in your scenario?

Comment: @Wolff I don't know if the character itself is a vector, are characters vectors?...

Comment: @JohnsonTarof, yes! The vector data is saved in the font file. So the only way a user can display the letters or symbols from a font is if they have it installed or if you provide it via CSS rules. That is what I meant with my initial comment. There is no way you can draw custom graphics on a users screen which doesn't involve the user downloading the data.

Comment: @Wolff ------ unless if the browser itself contains these graphics (such as all Unicode characters) right? Well, bummer... Maybe I should tried writing a suggestion to Unicode organization and meanwhile use the image...

Comment: @JohnsonTarof, or just use the image and let it be? There are thousands of companies in the world. They come and go. And change their logos. And have multicolored logos. Can't all have their own Unicode character.

Comment: @Wolff or indeed. Let me tell you something of the course, I believe that we are heading towards an age in which companies will come and go significantly slower.

Comment: @JohnsonTarof, you might be right ... let's give them just a tiny bit of resistance by *not* adding their logos to Unicode. 

Comment: @JohnsonTarof This question is several months old, but I just wanted to say that browsers themselves _do not_ “contain these graphics (such as all Unicode characters)”. A Unicode character is a simple code point which the OS (generally not the browser directly) translates into a call to fetch a specific glyph from the font being used. The actual character (the glyph, the vector shape) is not stored in the browser, but in the _font_. In order to display the glyph, the browser has to have access to the font, which must be installed on the system or downloaded/included as a web font.